# How to add Arabic Buckwalter keyboard layout in Windows 10/11

Tags: windows, keyboard, microsoft

On my Linux machine, I was able to install the [`Arabic Buckwalter`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckwalter_transliteration) keyboard layout.

However, on my Windows VM, I couldn't find that layout in the list of downloadable layouts in the system settings.
Does it go by another name? Or is there a way to add it manually?

Thanks.

Comment: I also want to install Arabic Buckwalter keyboard layout on Windows, but sadly I don't seem to find any solution.

Comment: I ended up making a custom layout (based on Buckwalter) using [MSKLC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134)
@BetzalelMaor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom layout using [MSKLC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134).